# Convolution2D + LSTM versus ConvLSTM2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Are `1` and `2` the same?

1. Use `Convolution2D` layers and `LSTM` layers
2. Use `ConvLSTM2D`

If there is any difference, could you explain it for me?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They are not exactly the same, here is why:

#### 1. Use `Convolution2D` layers and `LSTM` layers

As it is known, `Convolution2D` serves well for capturing image or spatial features, whilst `LSTM` are used to detect correlations over time. However, by stacking these kind of layers, the correlation between space and time features may not be captured properly.

#### 2. Use `ConvLSTM2D`

To solve this, [Xingjian Shi et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04214v1) proposed a network structure able to capture spatiotemporal correlations, namely `ConvLSTM`. In Keras, this is reflected in the [`ConvLSTM2D`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#convlstm2d) class, which computes convolutional operations in both the input and the recurrent transformations.

#### Keras code

Too illustrate this, you can see [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py) the `LSTM` code, if you go to the `call` method from `LSTMCell`, you'd only see:

```python
    x_i = K.dot(inputs_i, self.kernel_i)
    x_f = K.dot(inputs_f, self.kernel_f)
    x_c = K.dot(inputs_c, self.kernel_c)
    x_o = K.dot(inputs_o, self.kernel_o)
```

Instead, the [`ConvLSTM2DCell`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional_recurrent.py) class calls:

```python
    x_i = self.input_conv(inputs_i, self.kernel_i, self.bias_i, padding=self.padding)
    x_f = self.input_conv(inputs_f, self.kernel_f, self.bias_f, padding=self.padding)
    x_c = self.input_conv(inputs_c, self.kernel_c, self.bias_c, padding=self.padding)
    x_o = self.input_conv(inputs_o, self.kernel_o, self.bias_o, padding=self.padding)
    h_i = self.recurrent_conv(h_tm1_i, self.recurrent_kernel_i)
    h_f = self.recurrent_conv(h_tm1_f, self.recurrent_kernel_f)
    h_c = self.recurrent_conv(h_tm1_c, self.recurrent_kernel_c)
    h_o = self.recurrent_conv(h_tm1_o, self.recurrent_kernel_o)
```

Where:

```python
def input_conv(self, x, w, b=None, padding='valid'):
    conv_out = K.conv2d(x, w, strides=self.strides,
                        padding=padding,
                        data_format=self.data_format,
                        dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
    if b is not None:
        conv_out = K.bias_add(conv_out, b,
                              data_format=self.data_format)
    return conv_out

def recurrent_conv(self, x, w):
    conv_out = K.conv2d(x, w, strides=(1, 1),
                        padding='same',
                        data_format=self.data_format)
    return conv_out
```

In `LSTM`, the equivalent for `h_x` (recurrent transformations) would be:

```python
K.dot(h_tm1_x, self.recurrent_kernel_x)
```

Instead of `ConvLSTM2D`'s:

```python
self.recurrent_conv(h_tm1_x, self.recurrent_kernel_x)
```

These kind of transformations could not be computed with stacked `Conv2D` and `LSTM` layers.

Comment: so, if the reason is to capture spatiotemporal of data at the same time, the next question is: what is the difference **ConvLSTM2D** and **Conv3D** ?

Answer (score 7):

> 1. Use Convolution2D layers and LSTM layer

In this technique, you stack convolution and LSTM layers. The convolutional layers help you to learn the spatial features and the LSTM helps you learn the correlation in time.

> 2.Use ConvLSTM2D

ConvLSTM is a LSTM in which the gates (input to state and state to state transitions) are convolution operations.
Research paper- [Convolutional LSTM Network: A Machine Learning Approach for Precipitation Nowcasting](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04214)

[More about ConvLSTM in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468918/appplication-of-convlstm2d-layers/49472074#49472074)